# Shortcut Command "ed" to START Sublime Text

Tags: linux, bash, sublimetext2

I'm used to creating the following `ed.cmd` file on my Windows PATH which launches my favorite editor:

```
START "Editor" "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\sublime.exe" %1
```

I'd like to do the same thing in Linux but run up against a few challenges:

1. `ed` seems to be reserved/exist. I can compromise on this an use `edi` if need be.
2. I need to launch the editor asynchronously (as in START in Windows). Typing `subl myfile.js` from the console "interrupts" my console session until sublime is closed again.
3. I don't know how the .cmd file equivalent (in Bash) should look

So I'd be grateful for a bash script to do the above and instructions on how to install it on my path so it's globally accessible.

Answer (score 2):

`ed` isn’t reserved; it just already exists. You can prioritize your own script by listing its directory earlier in `$PATH` than `/usr/bin` (or wherever `ed` is – see `command -v ed`).

It’d be fun to use `ed` for this, so, in your shell of choice:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir -p .bin
$ ed
i
#!/bin/sh
subl "$@" &
.
wq .bin/ed
$ chmod +x .bin/ed
```

where `$` is the prompt and everything else is something you type. Now just put `PATH=~/.bin:$PATH` in your `.profile`.

You could also make it a function in your `.bashrc`. That’s probably cleaner.

```
ed() {
    subl "$@" &
}
```